# Asp.Net Webservice "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: c#, web-services

I know this problem exist in stackoverflow. but mine is seems different.
I don't see any problem. but it happens sometimes in runtime.

**Exception i got :** 
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] GetTemplateAndPicture(System.String):
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

**Here is my code :** Could anyone please see and tell me what happens?

```
public static List<string> GetTemplateAndPicture(string sessionID) 
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            try
            {

                // get the session data from the list.
                 SessionData sData = null;
                 try
                 {
                     //sData = SessionDataList.Find(p => p.SessionID.Equals(sessionID));
                     foreach (SessionData sessiondata in SessionDataList.ToList<SessionData>())
                     {
                         if (sessiondata != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessiondata.SessionID))
                         {
                             if (sessiondata.SessionID.Equals(sessionID))
                             {
                                 sData = sessiondata;
                                 break;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     RightPatientRemoteWebserviceLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + ":" + ex.Message);
                 }
                // get template data from session data
                string templateData = (sData == null) ? string.Empty : sData.TemplateData;

                // get picture data from session data
                string pictureData = (sData == null) ? string.Empty : sData.PictureData;

                string errorCode = (sData == null) ? string.Empty : sData.ErrorCode;

                // remove the session data from the list. no more usage with this data.
                if (sData != null && SessionDataList.Count>0)
                SessionDataList.Remove(sData);

                // create a list for sending.

                data.Add(templateData);
                data.Add(pictureData);
                data.Add(errorCode);
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RightPatientRemoteWebserviceLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "::" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() + ":" + ex.Message);
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: You'd be better off tracing `ex.ToString()`, which will give you a stack trace that will help you find the offending line.  If you've compiled in Debug mode the trace will include the line number where the exception is thrown.

Comment: The exception should occure in  SessionDataList.Remove(sData); or foreach (SessionData sessiondata in SessionDataList.ToList<SessionData>())
        im dam sure. but cant handle. @joe

Comment: Are you using Threads? Somewhere else a Thread is messing with the global SessionDataList?

Comment: _it happens sometimes in runtime_ in combination with `SessionDataList.Remove(sData);` hints at a threading problem.

Comment: No im not using thread here. but when im doing foreach to this SessionDataList. in this time it can be updated form any other method. so in this case to prevent exception i use .toList<SessionData>() to it in foreach. you can see. @Steve

Comment: So is there any way to prevent this? @Henk Holterman

Comment: You tagged [ASP.NET], could SessionDataList be shared between Requests or Sessions ?

Comment: Sorry for adding tag of ASP.NET. i removed this form the tag list. but actually im using a asp.net webservice and its a List object im having problem with. this list object will hold data that comes form several other client end and return the exact session data  to the caller client that call this method. im having a big problem with this exception, cause its not happening all the time, ones or twice a day. i have to solve this issue. please do something or suggest what can i do for this kind of situation. it cannot be shared between request. @ Henk Holteman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the global list you are using is not thread safe. cause you say "list object will hold data that comes form several other client end" in your last comment. so if they all try to modify the list at the same time when you are trying to delete an item form the list it gonna crash. so for thread safety just modify your global list as private and made 2 public method. one for to add item to the list and another for to remove item from the list. of course don't forget to lock the global list that is SessionDataList.

so when you need to add or remove the item to or form list just use below specified two public method.

code snippets is something like this:

```
private static SessionDatalist<SessionData> SessionDataList=new SessionDatalist<SessionData>();

public addSessionData()
{
  lock(SessionDataList)
  {

   //add list item here to the SessionDataList
  }
}

public removeSessionData()
{
  lock(SessionDataList)
  {

     //remove item from SessionDataList
  }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks @Forest Gump. i am trying you suggestion and let you know the updates.